# How are relationships between related models in ember-data established

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I had assumed that if a model in ember-data contained an id related to a second model, then the id could also be used to establish a belongsTo relationship to the second model object, as per the issue I created [here on github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/783). Apparently that is not the case.

Does anyone know the circumstance(s) required to have relationships between two objects that both exist in ember-data's store be related to each other? Do the related objects have to be loaded at the same time? (or come through on the same request in the case of the RESTAdapter) in order for the id references to work? In the event they don't come through on the same request, is there anyway to establish that relationship on later requests without have to add event handlers for the requests that look for relationships and set them manually? Here is an example of the issue I'm seeing:

```
App.ModelA = DS.Model.extend({
  name:      DS.attr('string'),
  modelBId:  DS.attr('number'),
  modelB:    DS.belongsTo('App.ModelB')
});

App.ModelB = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ModelB.find(2);       // returns an object

modelA.get('modelBId');   // returns 2
modelA.get('modelB');     // returns null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of associated objects are useful when you want to load / save data, from a REST API for example. Then you can use the RESTAdapter and send the ID of the related objects.

For example, for a `belongsTo` relationship, ember-data assume that you will send a key `model_b_id` with the ID of the related object. Then ember-data will handle the loading of this object, typically by a call to the API : `GET model_b/the_id`

It is also possible to load the associated objects by embedding them instead of giving a reference by id.

Please see other questions on StackOverflow and example / test in ember-data projects for more example.

Comment: The thing I still don't get is that the API is sending a model_b_id along with the modelA api call. However, all the modelB objects had been previously loaded using a `ModelB.find()` call, so another API call to get the modelB data associated with modelA isn't necessary, nor is sideloading data (and for this data, I don't want to sideload it, the ModelA.find() calls happen frequently in the application, but ModelB is kind of like a lookup table with a limited number of infrequently changing values). So, is ember-data not finding the related modelB objects b/c data isn't sideloaded?

Comment: If the related object is already loaded as you said model is, ember-data won't fire an ajax request but take it from the identity map. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this on Adrien, I really appreciate it. I feel like you're close to helping me resolve my confusion. What is the identity map? Googling makes me think it might be the same thing as what I'm thinking of as the store (kind of an in memory browser db). If that were the case though, I would think the last `modelA.get('modelB')` would return the modelB object associated with model_b_id 2. Since it's not, perhaps the identity map is something else. How can I make the modelB with ID 2 that already exists be associated with modelA with modelBId of 2 through identity map?

Comment: Yes, the identity map is what is keeping the loaded record in the browser memory. It should work as you said, if it's not, you may have a problem in the loading of the `modelA` or maybe the attribute `modelBId` is messed things up, could you try without it ?

Comment: I was thinking having the modelBId in there as an attribute might have been messing it up previously and so I removed it. Didn't have any impact, `modelA.get('modelB')` still returns null. Could it be some kind of caching setting? I don't think I have any kind of explicit caching setup around either of the models (or their attributes) but maybe there is some kind of implicit caching? I'll go ahead and mark the question as answered b/c there was so much info here, but I'm still seeing the problem.

Comment: I have no idea why this could happen, it will be helpful if you can reproduce it on a simple JS fiddle ? I know there is some tools to simulate API answer with js fiddle but cannot remember the name now.

Answer (score 2):

Adam,

I'm starting with Ember Data myself and the confusion is usually due to its many automations/assumptions of the REST API. try:

```
App.ModelA = DS.Model.extend({
  name:      DS.attr('string'),
  modelB:    DS.belongsTo('App.ModelB')
});
```

Where the REST API returns a Model A like:

```
{"model_a":{"name": "Adam", "model_b_id": 2}}
```

Effectively and by default Ember Data tacks '_id', for any belongsTo relationship, onto the decamelized attribute name, or '_ids' to any hasMany.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I appreciate the response. In this case, my API is returning a key for "model_b_id" associated with "model_a" (which is how the modelBId property is being set on the modelA instance), so I think there might be something else going on. Really good tip though, thanks for jumping in. I still need to work up the jsFiddle showing it happening.